# Unable to insert Ajax return into HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, dom

I'm trying to use a PHP file to process serialized info from an Ajax request. I want to send back the value of each form field to be further manipulated by javascript (inserted into a div). The result is not being inserted into the HTML. When I alert the result I get `{"return":["<p>form value for name<\/p>","<p>form value for description<\/p>"]}` Any suggestions?

EDIT: Updated question with relevant HTML and revised PHP code.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
   <h5>Heading</h5>
   <div id="formBasicResults"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
.on('success.form.fv', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $form = $(e.target);
  var bv = $form.data('formValidation');
  $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize())
    .done(function (result) {
      $('#formBasicResults').html(result.responseText);
      alert(result);
  },'json');
});
```

PHP:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
  if (!isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    $token = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
    $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
    $_SESSION['token_time'] = time();
  } else {
    $token = $_SESSION['token'];
  }
}

foreach($_POST as $key = > $value) {
  $temp = is_array($value) ? $value : trim($value);
  $_SESSION[$key] = $temp;
}

$expected = array(
  'name' = > 'string',
  'description' = > 'string',
);

foreach($expected AS $key) {
  if (!empty($_POST[$key])) {
    $ {$key} = $_POST[$key];
  } else {${$key} = NULL;
  }
}

foreach($expected AS $key = > $type) {
  if (empty($_POST[$key])) {
    $ {$key} = NULL;
    continue;
  }
  if (!isset($ {
    $key})) {
    $ {$key} = NULL;
  }
}
function safe( $value ) {
htmlentities( $value, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8' );
return ($value);
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$description = $_POST['description'];

$return['result']=array();
if(!empty($name)){$return['result'][]= '<p>' . safe($name) . '</p>';}
if(!empty($description)){$return['result'][]= '<p>' . safe($description) . '</p>';}
echo json_encode($return);
```

Comment: Your result doesn't have responseText property. You have to put into html what you have there or change what you print out in PHP.

Comment: also add `dataType` argument to `$.post` if you haven't set content header as "application/json"

Comment: @user86745458 I'm confused, why did you edit the code in my original post? Seems like you changed it enough that it should've been answer instead. Also, I see you replaced `$_POST['name']` but not `$_POST['description']`. Was that intentional?

Comment: After edit by user86745458, I'm now getting following result in alert: `{"description":[],"return":["<p>text for name<\/p>","<p>text for description<\/p>"]}`

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
$('#formBasicResults').html(result['return'][0]);
```

or

```
$('#formBasicResults').html(result['return'][1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
if ($_POST['token'] == $_SESSION['token']) 
{$return['return']=array();
if(!empty($_POST['name'])){$return['return'][] = '<p>' . htmlentities($_POST['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '</p>'; 
if(!empty($_POST['description'])){$return['return'][] = '<p>' . htmlentities($_POST['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '</p>';}
echo json_encode($return); }}
```

do this:

```
$return['responseText']='';
if ($_POST['token'] == $_SESSION['token']) 
{

if(!empty($_POST['name'])){

$return['responseText'] .= '<p>' . htmlentities($_POST['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '</p>'; 

if(!empty($_POST['description'])){

$return['responseText'] .= '<p>' . htmlentities($_POST['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '</p>';}

}
}
echo json_encode($return);
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, The info is still getting inserted into my HTML.

Comment: If you are seeing json array inserted into your html, set jQuery post dataType to json. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: I modified my code quite a bit and added json dataType, but the problem persists.